# Get distibution depending on three random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Given the function $\text{result} = \frac{a*b}{1-c}$ with 3 independent equally distributed random variables $a$, $b$, and $c$, how do I derive the distribution of $\text{result}$?
How can I get the range of the top 20 percent of $\text{result}$?
I did it all in Excel to get approximations, but my math is a bit rusted.

Comment: You tend to ask interesting 'outside the box' questions, that are somewhat under-specified. I went back in time to excavate this one for a bit of exploration.

Comment: The "underspecified" part comes probably from my non-math background. Therefore I often don't really know if I have all relevant facts and correct names to describe the problem accurately. If I remember my question correctly, the variables were uniformly distributed between min and max values both between 0 and 1.

Comment: I guessed something like that. Then it's my case (1). But my W has a mean only if the denominator doesn't touch or overlap 0, as in case (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have three independent, "equally distributed" random variables, which I will
call $X_i,$ for $i = 1,2,3.$. I take this to mean that the three random variables have
the same distribution. Whether your question makes practical sense depends on
what distribution that is.

You want to know about the distribution of 
$$ W = \frac{X_1X_2}{1-X_3}.$$ Notice that if the distribution of $X_3$ puts probability
in a neighborhood of $1,$ then $W$ will not have a mean. But you are interested in the 80th
percentile of $W,$ so let's use simulation in R statistical software to look at four distributions for the $X_i.$

(1) $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Unif(0,1).$ In this case, the
80th quantile of $W$ is about 1.25. Its distribution has a long heavy tail
to the right owing to values of $X_3$ near 1. Accordingly, the histogram in panel (1) of the figure below is
truncated to omit values above 1.2.

```
m = 10^6
x1 = runif(m);  x2 = runif(m);  x3 = runif(m)
w = x1 * x2/(1 - x3)
quantile(w, .8)
##      80% 
## 1.249817
```

(2) $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Unif(2,3).$ In this case, the
80th quantile of $W$ is about -3.33, and $E(W) \approx -4.33.$  The histogram in panel (2) shows a moderately left-skewed distribution, which one ought to be able to derive
analytically.

(3) $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Norm(0,1).$ In this case, the
80th quantile of $W$ is about 0.58. Its distribution has long heavy tails
in both directions, owing to values of $X_3$ near 1. Accordingly, the histogram in panel (1) of the figure below is
truncated to show only values with $|W| < 0.6.$

(4) $X_i$ have a 'delayed exponential distribution'. That is,
$X_i = Y_i + 3,$ where $Y_i \sim Exp(rate=1).$ In this case, the
80th quantile of $W$ is about -3.79, and $E(W) \approx -5.78.$ The denominator of $W$ takes negative
values separated from 0. The histogram in panel (4) shows left-skewed distribution with a thin left tail, and one ought to be able to derive
the distribution analytically.

[image]